# jQuery addClass not working

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm using the following code:

If i inspect it in Firebug, then last-active gets applied to the last image, but the initial 'active' class never gets applied??

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=59597329@N08&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("<img src='" + item.media.m + "'></img>").appendTo("#mac");
    });
});

$("#mac img:first").addClass('active');

function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#mac img.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#mac img:last');

var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#mac img.active');

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( slideSwitch, 5000 );
});
```

Comment: Are there any images inside the `#mac` element before the `getJSON` function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your `$.getJSON` and `$("#mac img:first").addClass('active');` code inside your initialization function (when the DOM is ready), else it may run when the page is not loaded yet:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=59597329@N08&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
      $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
          $("<img src='" + item.media.m + "'></img>").appendTo("#mac");
      });
  });

  $("#mac img:first").addClass('active');
  setInterval( slideSwitch, 5000 );
});
```

Comment: hi, alex, all the code above is in the document.ready function!

Comment: `$(function() {});` and `$(document).ready(function() {});` are equivalent. More info: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ - Try to get the `setInterval` outside of the `$(function)` bit.